# Greyout entire form css

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have to greyout an entire form and make it disabled, if is possible using  (controlled by a Javascript)

My idea was:

```
<div style="background-color: gray; opacity:0.7; z-index:2;">
       <h:form prependId="false" id="login_form" style="x-index:1;">
             ...button
             ...inputBox
       </h:form>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work properly, infact the grey of the DIV is only in the background and I want grey on ALL the object in the form (inputbox, button, text, etc...)

I prefer with just one DIV so I don't have to change the style of each object (button disabled, inputbox disabled, etc...)

Thanks

Comment: What is  `<h:form>`? That is not regular HTML.

Comment: I am using PrimeFaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways this can be achieve - one simple, pure-CSS based approach would be to define a CSS class `.disable-form` and apply it to the `<div/>` that encloses your form when you want your form to be disabled.

You could do this like so:

```css
.disable-form {

   /* Make form elements appear disabled against grey background */
   background-color: gray;
   opacity:0.5; 

   /* Prevent user interaction with form while disabled */
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form prependId="false" id="login_form">
    <div>
      <label>Some field</label>
      <input />
    </div>
    <label>Some field not wrapped in div</label>
    <input />
  </form>
</div>


<br>
<br>
<button id="toggle-disable">Click to toggle form disable</button>
<script>

document.getElementById('toggle-disable')
.addEventListener('click', function() {

   document.getElementById('login_form')
  .parentNode
  .classList
  .toggle('disable-form');   
  
});
</script>
```

Note that I've adjusted the HTML in this code sample for the purpose of demonstrating the technqiue - the key here is defining and apply the `disable-form` CSS to achieve the desired affect on your form.

Comment: @Wal you're welcome - please consider accepting this answer if it has helped :-)